# function returning array as an pointer

Tags: c++, arrays

I have tried to implement a simple function which returns the pointer to first element in array.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int * func(int n)
{
    int arr[n];
    for (int a = 0; a <n; a++)
    {
        arr[a]=a;
    }
    return arr;
}
int main()
{
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    int * arr=func(n);
    for (int i = 0; i <n; i++)
    {
        cout<<*(arr+i)<<endl;
    }

 }
```

I have assumed that array occupies contiguous block of memory,then why the output of this program isn't what expected.

if n=10 then output is

```
0
-1216233191
-1215824576
-1215824576
-1215855028
-1215820256
-1074779464
-1215820256
-1074779464
134514382
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int * func(int n)
{
    int arr[n];       <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<local variable to this function.
    for (int a = 0; a <n; a++)
    {
        arr[a]=a;
    }
    return arr;
}
```

You should not return address of local variables...

Comment: You can, it's just not advised.

Comment: Oh yes, you can. The pit of hell is open for all comers.

Comment: Corrected to avoid misinterpretation

Comment: The key expressions here are "can" and "should not". ;)

Comment: if it is not safe to do that than what is the use of any function like this int *func()  and can you please also tell me if there is another way to accomplish the same thing i was trying to do.

Comment: Yes you can create object on heap and return it...

Comment: then how we can use any function of type int *func() safely. it would be good if you give me a example.

Comment: example would be:-  int* func() { int* ptr = new int; return ptr; }

Comment: and isn't the ptr local variable or it remains in the memory and  it will be there until we use delete??and also can you please tell me any source to learn c++ or how you learnt it?